# Arbitrarily long amicable chains

Tags: number-theory

An amicable chain of natural numbers of length n is an ordered n-tuple of distinct naturals (a_1,...a_n) such that the sum of the proper divisors of a_i equals a_{i+1}, for all i mod n.  Is it known if there are arbitrarily long amicable chains? The longest I can find is here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ChainsOfAmicableNumbers/

Comment: Does [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004270/amicable-chains-of-numbers) have examples of longer ones?

Comment: "i mod n" is confusing. You probably mean a cycle containing $a_1,\cdots ,a_n$. If the numbers form such a cycle they are also called social numbers. If I remember right, a cycle with length $28$ is known, but there might exist longer known cycles.

Comment: I just mean the tuple is arranged in a circle. Is it less confusing if I index the tuple (a_0,...,a_{n-1})?